# how to update database with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update MongoDB database with mongoose

Works but I can't get a call back with new data

```
 Templates.updateOne((req.query, req.body))
```

does not work

```
Templates.updateOne(req.query, req.body, { new: true }, (err, data) => {
      console.log("just call back", data);
    })
```

the data that is coming from req.query

```
 {title: "Hello World"}
```

the data that is coming from req.body

```
 {_ref: "your ref}
```

I am hoping to be able to update with callback and new data to console.log

Comment: You really should avoid passing `req.query` and `req.body` to Mongo directly, because these come straight from the browser. Anybody can write anything in them, send them to your server, and have whatever code executed. This is very unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc, [Document.prototype.updateOne()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-updateOne) does not accept `{new:true}` (it is a native MongoDB command, I believe), but [Model.findOneAndUpdate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) does.

Comment: ok. just tried but all back is null with no change to db. If I  template.findOneAndUpdate({title: "Hello World"}) it works but what does not work is Templates.findOneAndUpdate(req.query) which is the same data